# Get marker of the Map as View

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, quickaction

I am using the Quick Action to display the set of items. When i click a button , Quick Action displays above the button. but i want to display the Quick Action above the marker in Map when i click on the button. Is it possible to get the Marker of Map as a View ?

```
quickAction = new QuickAction(this, QuickAction.VERTICAL); 

        ActionItem parkItem     = new ActionItem(0, "park", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.park));
        quickAction.addActionItem(parkItem);
    quickAction.show(view);
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the setInfoWindowAdapter of the  MapFragment using

```
mapFragment.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {
            // here you can inflate your QuickAction view according to the pressed marker
            }
        });
```